# Jquery-Layout throws error because $N.selector is undefined

Tags: jquery

I am trying to port a legacy project and it used Jquery-Layout. When I try to start the application it gets to the line...

```
sC.selector = $N.selector.split(".slice")[0];
```

And barfs...

> Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Now I don't know a lot about this library but if I breakpoint at the point of failure I see `$N instanceof jQuery` returns true and I see a DOM element in the collection. Is it possible for it not to have a selector?

Comment: If you are referring to [this](https://api.jquery.com/selector/), it has been removed from jq3.x

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Yeah this library doesn't even have an npm repo or github so I am guessing it is not kept very up to date.

Comment: If you downgrade to jq2.x, it would work, still if it is your issue

Comment: Not going to happen so I just forked the project after I finally found the GH. Thanks though!

Comment: @Jackie Were you ever able to fix this issue? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Don't remember sorry about that, I think I just moved away from this lib

Answer (score 4):

For jquery.layout 1.4.4 just comment row 1831: sC.selector = $N.selector.split(".slice")[0]; and all works normally (tested on jQuery v3.3.1)