# R rhandsonetable in htmlTemplate / JqueryLayout not working

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable, jquery-layout, html-templates

I want to create a shinyApp with a **custom UI**, using the `htmlTemplate` function from shiny and the JQuery Layouts from [here](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/downloads.cfm).

Displaying tables using the DT framework works fine, but I would like to use the `rhandsontable` package. Unfortunately, this is not as easy as including a DT-table.

The browser console gives back this error:

```
`language` is deprecated since version 1.6.0. Use `culture` instead handsontable.full.min.js:36:7951

jQuery.Deferred exception: $N.selector is undefined _initContainer@http://127.0.0.1:5340/layout-master/source/stable/jquery.layout.js:1832:3
_create@http://127.0.0.1:5340/layout-master/source/stable/jquery.layout.js:1549:3
$.fn.layout@http://127.0.0.1:5340/layout-master/source/stable/jquery.layout.js:5124:6
@http://127.0.0.1:5340/LayoutScript.js:9:13
j@http://127.0.0.1:5340/jquery-3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:29997
g/</k<@http://127.0.0.1:5340/jquery-3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:30313
 undefined jquery.min.js:2:31569

TypeError: $N.selector is undefined[Weitere Informationen]
```

The app-code can be found [here](https://github.com/trafficonese/rhandsonetable) and run with

```
runGitHub(repo = "rhandsonetable", username = "trafficonese")
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49064472/3682794) solved the issue for now, but Im not sure what further effects it might have..

Comment: Using the [EasyUI](https://www.jeasyui.com/) library for such an approach is definitly the better option.